# Python & NetworkX for Network Topology Data

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I tried thousands of times to apply "NetworkX" Python library to analyze the datasets found by this link:

```
http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/topology
```

As long as I execute my Python code to the data found there I got, for example, some unrealistic results.

```
g = nx.read_weighted_edgelist('out.topology')
g.size()
0
```

0 as a result for this huge data is completely wrong !

Could you please help me to read this data through "NetworkX" Python library ?

Comment: What version of networkx are you trying?  I am using 2.0 and I get errors from `nx.read_weighted_edgelist('out.topology')`, so the graph is not created.  What is the exact command you're using and the exact error message (if any)?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and I assume I am using the latest version of networkX, since I have just installed it by "pip install networkx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned trying reading the list gets errors. However, if you get rid of the first line (`% sym positive`) and try the code below to create your graph it should be fine:

```
import networkx as nx

with open("out.topology", 'rt') as f:
    g = nx.parse_edgelist(f, create_using=nx.DiGraph(), data=[('weight', float), ('timestamp', float)])
```

The data contains 4 columns: source | target | weight | timestamp of edge.

Just include that info in the arguments as shown in my snippet.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Rodgdor. If you please read the read-file, you will know that the data represents an undirected graph. I think, it is better to use "nx.Graph()" instead of "nx.DiGraph()" as you suggested.

Comment: By the way, I have done some codes looks like yours, but I still get "g.size()" equals zero, which is logically not correct !

Comment: I have just convert the data to "txt" extenstion and I got a reasonable results for the data :)

Comment: reading the `README` file I realize it says it's a multigraph, so you may want to use `nx.MultiGraph()` instead. The `.txt` extension should do absolutely no difference, how odd.

Comment: 'with open("tplgy.csv", 'rt') as f:
    g = nx.parse_edgelist(f, create_using=nx.Graph(), data=[('S',float),('D', float),
                                                            ('weight', float), ('timestamp', float)])' and I got the following error: **IndexError: Edge data ['1', '1266192000'] and data_keys [('S', <type 'float'>), ('D', <type 'float'>), ('weight', <type 'float'>), ('timestamp', <type 'float'>)] are not the same length
**

Comment: yes that's because it should read `data=[('weight', float), ('timestamp', float)]`, the first two columns are not data.

Comment: I am sorry, It is written that this data represents undirected format graph by "Network Info" in the main web page in http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/topology

Comment: On the other hand, testing the data graph by  ' >>> 1 in g     # check if node in graph ' gives us ***False*** even though the len(g) = 34761 ;(

Comment: You can get the code to ignore the first line by using the optional argument `comments='%'`.  This tells networkx to treat any line that starts with the string `'%'` as a comment.

Comment: @AilMansour try `'1' in g` instead.